# for loop not working in generate html file via bash script

Tags: bash

When I am running following bash script-

```
#!/bin/bash
items="b.js
   a.js
   c.js"
startScript='<script src="'
endScript='"></script>'
for item in $items
do
  echo $startScript$item$endScript
done
```

Output:

```
 <script src="c.js"></script>
 <script src="a.js"></script>
 <script src="b.js"></script>
```

I want to run this for loop inside generated html file via a bash script. For loop is not working here.

```
#!/bin/bash
items="b.js
   a.js
   c.js"
startScript='<script src="'
endScript='"></script>'
cat << noEcho
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>  Bash Script  </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
for item in $items
do
 echo $startScript $item $endScript
done
</BODY>
</HTML>
noEcho
```

Comment: Don't store lists in strings -- use arrays for that. `files=( b.js a.js c.js )`, then `for item in "${files[@]}"; ...`

Comment: First, `/bin/sh` isn't always bash. Second, how is this not working? Third, I'd prefer `printf` to `echo`. Fourth, why bash instead of perl?

Comment: And you need to use `$()` if you want to substitute the output of some code into heredoc body text.

Comment: Also, you're never assigning anything to `$items`, so I don't know why you'd expect `for item in $items` to do anything useful even if you *did* properly have it inside of a command substitution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if I am using array  getting Syntax error: "(" unexpected  and  for this "${files[@]}"  -- Bad substitution

Comment: That means your shell isn't bash. Use `bash`, not `sh` -- or stop tagging your question [tag:bash] when that's not actually what you want to use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I edit my question. Sorry about this

Comment: Note the `#!/bin/bash` (not `#!/bin/sh`) shebang in my answer. Similarly, you can't run a bash script with `sh scriptname` and expect it to work correctly; bash and POSIX sh are two different languages.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got your point. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example with the most glaring bugs fixed:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=( b.js a.js c.js)
startScript='<script src="'
endScript='"></script>'
cat << noEcho
<html><head><title>Bash Script</title></head><body>
$(
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
 echo "${startScript}${file}${endScript}"
done
)
</body></html>
noEcho
```

You can see the above running, with its output, at http://ideone.com/rSsO9H.

Some notes:

- Don't do this. Really. Use a real template language that understands HTML syntax and knows how to escape content properly; you'll find securing this kind of code next to impossible if/when dealing with dynamic data.
- Strings are not arrays. If you want an array, use an actual array.
- If you want the output of a given piece of code to be substituted into a string (or, in this case, a heredoc), it needs to be in a command substitution: `$()`